# flutter reset only custom widget state after it's optional function execution

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page where we have some pickup session when you select a pickup session at the bottom SwipeActionButton widget activate

[image]

now user can swipe right side and after swipe complete an async function execute which most time hit an api so if api result is success app goes to next page no problem here but if api result gave an error it shows a dialog

[image]

Press Ok and dialog pop but SwipeActionButton widget still show complete swipe how I can reset it.
[image]

code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: NormalAppBar(
        title: Text("Assign Requests"),
      ),
      body: Consumer<PickupSessionProvider>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) => Stack(
          children: [
            widget.requestIds.length == 0
                ? _requestsLoaded
                    ? provider.unassignedRequestCount == 0
                        ? Center(
                            child: Text("No requests.",
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                          )
                        : _buildRequestsList(provider.unassignedRequests!)
                    : Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )
                : provider.pickupSessions!.length == 0
                    ? Center(
                        child: Text("No active pickup session.",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                      )
                    : ListView(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            child: Text(
                              "Select pickup session",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                            ),
                          ),
                          for (var pickupSession in provider.pickupSessions!)
                            _buildPickupSessionTile(pickupSession)
                        ],
                      ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: SwipeActionButton(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
                onDone: (_selectRequestList && requestIds.length == 0) ||
                        (!_selectRequestList &&
                            _selectedPickupSessionId == null)
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        var result = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) => _ProgressDialog(
                                requestIds: requestIds,
                                pickupSessionId: _selectedPickupSessionId),
                            barrierDismissible: true);
                        if (result == true) Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                      },
                doneText: "Assign request",
                disabledText: "Assign request",
                infoText: "Swipe to assign request",
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Custom SwipeActionButton widget

```
class SwipeActionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final Color doneColor;
  final Color swiperColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final String doneText;
  final String disabledText;
  final VoidCallback? onDone;
  final String? infoText;
  final double? width;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  SwipeActionButton({
    Key? key,
    this.height = 50,
    this.doneColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    this.swiperColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    this.textColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    required this.doneText,
    required this.disabledText,
    this.onDone,
    this.infoText,
    this.width,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.margin = EdgeInsets.zero
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SwipeActionButtonState createState() => _SwipeActionButtonState();
}

class _SwipeActionButtonState extends State<SwipeActionButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double swipePercent = 0.0;
  bool swipeDone = false;
  bool isDisabled = false;

  late Color backgroundColor;
  late AnimationController _controller;
   Animation<double>? _animation;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    backgroundColor = widget.backgroundColor ?? Color(0xff3344b31f);
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
              swipePercent = _animation?.value ??0;
            });
          })
          ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.completed && swipeDone) {
              widget.onDone!();
            }
          });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    _controller.reset();
    swipePercent = 0.0;
  }

  _onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      swipePercent =
          details.globalPosition.dx / MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      if (swipePercent > 0.90) swipeDone = true;
    });
  }

  _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (swipePercent > 0.90 || swipeDone) {
      _animation =
          Tween<double>(begin: swipePercent, end: 1).animate(_controller);
    } else {
      _animation =
          Tween<double>(end: 0, begin: swipePercent).animate(_controller);
    }
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isDisabled = widget.onDone == null;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: widget.margin,
      width: screenWidth - widget.margin.horizontal,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: widget.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isDisabled ? Colors.grey : Color(0xff3344b31f),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
              border: Border.all(
                color: isDisabled ? Colors.grey : Color(0xff3344b31f),
                width: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(widget.infoText ?? "",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .subtitle1!
                        .copyWith(color: widget.textColor))),
          ),
          Container(
            width: isDisabled
                ? screenWidth
                : lerpDouble(widget.height, screenWidth, swipePercent),
            height: widget.height,
            child: Center(
                child: Opacity(
                    opacity: isDisabled ? 1 : lerpDouble(0, 1, swipePercent)!,
                    child: Text(
                      isDisabled ? widget.disabledText : widget.doneText,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                      textScaleFactor:
                          isDisabled ? 1 : lerpDouble(0, 1, swipePercent),
                    ))),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isDisabled ? Colors.grey : null,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                /*   border: Border.all(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  width: 1.5,
                ), */
                gradient: isDisabled
                    ? null
                    : LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.center,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                        colors: [
                            widget.doneColor,
                            swipeDone ? widget.doneColor : backgroundColor
                          ])),
          ),
          isDisabled
              ? Container()
              : Positioned(
                  left: lerpDouble(
                      0, screenWidth -(15 +widget.margin.horizontal) - (widget.height * .9), swipePercent),
                  /* top: widget.height * .1,
                  bottom: widget.height * .1,
                   */
                  child: AbsorbPointer(
                      absorbing: swipeDone,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onHorizontalDragStart: _onDragStart,
                          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdate,
                          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
                          child: Opacity(
                              opacity: 1,
                              child: AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                height: widget.height,
                                width: widget.height,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      width: 1.5,
                                    ),
                                    boxShadow: swipeDone
                                        ? null
                                        : [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.black45,
                                                blurRadius: 4)
                                          ],
                                    color: swipeDone
                                        ? backgroundColor
                                        : widget.swiperColor),
                                child: swipeDone
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.check,
                                        size: 20,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                    : Icon(
                                        Icons.arrow_forward,
                                        size: 20,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                              ))))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some information on the widget SwipeActionButton, it seems to be a custom implementation.

Comment: Expose SwipeActionButton's state to parent widget so that parent can control it programmatically.

Comment: @Tanguy, I added the SwipeActionButton code

Comment: @SpikeL if you added some kind of example It will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how you can make the swipeButton reset in case the request doesn't return with a valid value.

The swipeButton's state is defined by its `swipeDone` and `swipePercent` variables. To achieve what you want you need to pass `swipeDone` as a parameter when constructing the widget.

```
class SwipeActionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  // Make swipeDone a class variable for the widget
  bool swipeDone;
  final double height;
  final Color doneColor;
  final Color swiperColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final String doneText;
  final String disabledText;
  final VoidCallback? onDone;
  final String? infoText;
  final double? width;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  SwipeActionButton({
    // Add it to the constructor
    required this.swipeDone,
    Key? key,
    this.height = 50,
    this.doneColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    this.swiperColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    this.textColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    required this.doneText,
    required this.disabledText,
    this.onDone,
    this.infoText,
    this.width,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.margin = EdgeInsets.zero,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SwipeActionButtonState createState() => _SwipeActionButtonState();
}
```

In _SwipeActionButtonState, delete `bool swipeDone = false;` and replace every `swipeDone` by `widget.swipeDone`.

You also need to reset the value of swipePercent.
You can do this by adding at the beginning of the swipeButton's build method :

`if (widget.swipeDone == false && swipePercent > 0.9) swipePercent = 0;`

Now you can declare the variable swipeDone in the parent widget state, pass it as a parameter and modify it whenever needed. For more clarity I give you an example with a simple widget that reset the swipe button when the floating action button is pressed.

[image: example gif]

Complete code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool swipeDone = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SwipeActionButton(
          disabledText: 'disabled',
          doneText: 'doneText',
          onDone: () {},
          swipeDone: swipeDone,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            swipeDone = false;
          });
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SwipeActionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  // Make swipeDone a class variable for the widget
  bool swipeDone;
  final double height;
  final Color doneColor;
  final Color swiperColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final String doneText;
  final String disabledText;
  final VoidCallback? onDone;
  final String? infoText;
  final double? width;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  SwipeActionButton({
    // Add it to the constructor
    required this.swipeDone,
    Key? key,
    this.height = 50,
    this.doneColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    this.swiperColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    this.textColor = const Color(0xff44b31f),
    required this.doneText,
    required this.disabledText,
    this.onDone,
    this.infoText,
    this.width,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.margin = EdgeInsets.zero,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SwipeActionButtonState createState() => _SwipeActionButtonState();
}

class _SwipeActionButtonState extends State<SwipeActionButton> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double swipePercent = 0.0;
  bool isDisabled = false;

  late Color backgroundColor;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double>? _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    backgroundColor = widget.backgroundColor ?? Color(0xff3344b31f);
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          swipePercent = _animation?.value ?? 0;
        });
      })
      ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed && widget.swipeDone) {
          widget.onDone!();
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    _controller.reset();
    swipePercent = 0.0;
  }

  _onDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      swipePercent = details.globalPosition.dx / MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      if (swipePercent > 0.90) widget.swipeDone = true;
    });
  }

  _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (swipePercent > 0.90 || widget.swipeDone) {
      _animation = Tween<double>(begin: swipePercent, end: 1).animate(_controller);
    } else {
      _animation = Tween<double>(end: 0, begin: swipePercent).animate(_controller);
    }
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.swipeDone == false && swipePercent > 0.9) swipePercent = 0;
    isDisabled = widget.onDone == null;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: widget.margin,
      width: screenWidth - widget.margin.horizontal,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: widget.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isDisabled ? Colors.grey : Color(0xff3344b31f),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
              border: Border.all(
                color: isDisabled ? Colors.grey : Color(0xff3344b31f),
                width: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(widget.infoText ?? "",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(color: widget.textColor))),
          ),
          Container(
            width: isDisabled ? screenWidth : lerpDouble(widget.height, screenWidth, swipePercent),
            height: widget.height,
            child: Center(
                child: Opacity(
                    opacity: isDisabled ? 1 : lerpDouble(0, 1, swipePercent)!,
                    child: Text(
                      isDisabled ? widget.disabledText : widget.doneText,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                      textScaleFactor: isDisabled ? 1 : lerpDouble(0, 1, swipePercent),
                    ))),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isDisabled ? Colors.grey : null,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                /*   border: Border.all(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  width: 1.5,
                ), */
                gradient: isDisabled
                    ? null
                    : LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.center,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                        colors: [widget.doneColor, widget.swipeDone ? widget.doneColor : backgroundColor])),
          ),
          isDisabled
              ? Container()
              : Positioned(
                  left:
                      lerpDouble(0, screenWidth - (15 + widget.margin.horizontal) - (widget.height * .9), swipePercent),
                  /* top: widget.height * .1,
                  bottom: widget.height * .1,
                   */
                  child: AbsorbPointer(
                      absorbing: widget.swipeDone,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onHorizontalDragStart: _onDragStart,
                          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdate,
                          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
                          child: Opacity(
                              opacity: 1,
                              child: AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                height: widget.height,
                                width: widget.height,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      width: 1.5,
                                    ),
                                    boxShadow:
                                        widget.swipeDone ? null : [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black45, blurRadius: 4)],
                                    color: widget.swipeDone ? backgroundColor : widget.swiperColor),
                                child: widget.swipeDone
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.check,
                                        size: 20,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                    : Icon(
                                        Icons.arrow_forward,
                                        size: 20,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                              ))))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tanguy thanks for the solution and time you put into this, but i know we can do something like this the problem with this if I use SwipeActionButton in 10 pages i have to maintain 10 variables for that and I don't want to do this I just want that it works as separate unite and don't depend on anything else
so if there more optimize way for that

Comment: @akshay-yadav what you want to achieve is not clear to me.
Do you want the swipeActionButton to always reset to zero after beeing slided to the end?